# How to get rid of the affine parameter in geodesic equation?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, geodesics

I encounter a problem that require me to calculate the geodesic of
$$ds^2=\frac{dx^2+dz^2}{z^2}$$ with the endpoint $(x_L,0),(x_R,0)$.   I get the answer $\ddot{x}-\frac{\dot{x}\dot{z}}{z}=0$ and $\ddot{z}+\frac{\dot{x}^2}{z}=0$.

However, I do not know how to solve these equations. The geodesic is suppoesed to be $$(x-x_L)(x-x_R)+z^2=0.$$ How can I get this? (I somehow understand that it is a circle, but I want a general method that can give me the geodesic for every metric)

Edit:
I was asked not to ask about homework questions. This is in fact from [arxiv 2108.09188](https://arxiv.org/abs/2108.09188) (2.16) but it looks like a homework question.

I see Prahar solve this specific system of equations. But the thing I would like to ask is that, given a general metric $$ds^2=g_{\mu\nu}dx^{\mu}dx^{\nu},$$ is there a way to find out the relationship $\frac{dx^{\mu}}{dx^{\nu}}$ in general? i.e., is there a way to get rid of the parameter $\lambda$ in the geodesic equation $$\frac{d^2x^{\alpha}}{d\lambda^2}+\Gamma^{\alpha}_{\beta\gamma}\frac{dx^{\beta}}{d\lambda}\frac{dx^{\gamma}}{d\lambda}=0~ ?$$

Comment: I think the "is there a general way to eliminate the parameters from a geodesic equation" is probably better asked as a different question, since it's quite different from "how do I solve this particular geodesic equation".

Answer (score 2):

The first equation is
$$
0 = \frac{x''}{x'}-\frac{z'}{z} = (\ln x')'-(\ln z)' \implies x'=az . 
$$
Plugging this into the second equation, we find
$$
0 =  z'' + \frac{x'^2}{z} = z'' + a^2 z \implies z=c \cos(a\lambda+b)
$$
We can now solve for $x$ as well,
$$
x = d + c \sin(a\lambda+b)
$$
The integration constants are fixed by the boundary conditions for the problem.
$$
\lambda=0: (x,z) = (x_L,0) \implies d+c \sin b = x_L , \quad c \cos b = 0 .
$$
$$
\lambda=1: (x,z) = (x_R,0) \implies d+c \sin (a+b) = x_R ,\quad c \cos(a+b) = 0 .
$$
The solutions are
$$
a=\pi,\quad b=\pi/2,\quad c = \frac{x_L-x_R}{2} ,\quad d = \frac{x_L+x_R}{2}. 
$$
The full solution is then
$$
z = \frac{x_R-x_L}{2} \sin ( \pi \lambda) , \quad x = \frac{x_R+x_L}{2} - \frac{x_R-x_L}{2} \cos(\pi \lambda) . 
$$
Finally, this implies
$$
\left( x - \frac{x_R+x_L}{2} \right)^2 + z^2 = \left( \frac{x_R-x_L}{2} \right)^2 \implies (x-x_L)(x-x_R) + z^2 = 0 . 
$$